# How do I create asynchronous HTTP requests, while still offering an object interface?

Tags: ruby, api, asynchronous

What is a good way to provide an easy to use object-style interface to an HTTP API, while still allowing asynchronous HTTP requests to be made?  For example, given the following code:

```
user = User.find(1) # /api/v1/users/1
f = user.foo # /api/v1/users/1/foo
b = user.bar # /api/v1/users/1/bar
```

Calls to the `foo` and `bar` methods could logically be called in parallel, but if possible I'd like to let the calling user have a clean way to declare their intent for parallel calls without getting into the details of the underlying HTTP lib.

I don't think invisibly automating the parallelization is a good idea, so that the calling code is explicit about its expectations. But, I do think something like the following block syntax could be extremely useful for front-end developers to be able to use when they know that a set of requests do not depend on each other.

```
# possible implementation?
user = User.find(1)
User.parallel do
  f = user.foo
  b = user.bar
end
```

Is this possible? How can I accomplish this using Ruby 1.9.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparent parallelization is generally accomplished through something called a future.  In ruby, both the lazy and promise gems have implementations of futures.  Here's an example with the promise gem:

```
require 'future'
user = User.find(1)
f = future{user.foo}
b = future{user.bar}
```

A future will run the computation in a block in a background thread, and any attempt to operate on f or b will block unless the background thread has already run to completion.

As a library designer, so long as your library is threadsafe, this should be fine in many cases, though it probably doesn't scale all that well in ruby.

Comment: i've chosen to investigate the celluloid gem, thanks!  [github](https://github.com/tarcieri/celluloid)

Answer (score 1):

The way this works using asynchronous SQL is something like this:

```
User.where(:id => 1).async_each do |user|
  Foo.where(:id => user.foo_id).async_each do |foo|
    # ... Do stuff with foo ...
  end
  Bar.where(:id => user.bar_id).async_each do |bar|
    # ... Do stuff with foo ...
  end
end
```

This is my experience with asynchronous Sequel, which is like ActiveRecord.

Keep in mind this is a lot of callbacks stacked together, so things can get sideways if you're not careful.